# Сопоставление 2 списков python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется два списка:

```
list1 = ['one/two/three', 'four/five/six', 'seven/eight/nine', 'ten/eleven/twelve']

list2 = ['one', 'seven']
```

Нужно получить на выходе те элементы list1, которые содержат ключи из list2
Элементы из list2 всегда соответствуют первой части элементов из list1

```
final_list = ['one/two/three', 'seven/eight/nine']
```

Понятно, что начинать нужно примерно с этого:

```
splitted = [i.split('/') for i in list1]
```

Но вот дальше не могу придумать правильный цикл, все закончились ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот простенько и понятно

```
list1 = ['one/two/three', 'four/five/six', 'seven/eight/nine', 'ten/eleven/twelve','ones/eleven/twelve']
list2 = ['one', 'seven',]
final_list = []

for elem in list1:
    if elem.split('/')[0] in list2:  # elem.split('/')[0] получаем массив и берем первый элемент этого массива
       final_list.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример перебора:

```
list1 = ['one/two/three', 'four/five/six', 'seven/eight/nine', 'ten/eleven/twelve']
list2 = ['one', 'seven']

final_list = [key for key in list1 if any(x in key for x in list2)]
print(final_list)
# ['one/two/three', 'seven/eight/nine']
```

Подробнее:

```
final_list = []

# Перебор ключей
for key in list1:
    # Если хоть 1 элемент из list2 есть в ключе
    if any(x in key for x in list2):
        final_list.append(key)

print(final_list)
# ['one/two/three', 'seven/eight/nine']
```

---

Поиск выполняется по всему ключу в `list1`, если нужно проверять только первый элемент, то в `any` вместо `x in key` писать: `x == key.split("/")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

создайте вспомогательный список для поиска по `list1`:

```
idx1 = [x.partition("/")[0] for x in list1]

print(idx1)
# ['one', 'four', 'seven', 'ten']
```

теперь можно легко искать по этому вспомогательному списку:

```
res = [list1[idx1.index(x2)] for x2 in list2 if x2 in idx1]
```

результат:

```
In [8]: res
Out[8]: ['one/two/three', 'seven/eight/nine']
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно искать, превратив список индексов в набор

```
plitted = [i.split('/') for i in list1]
set2=set(list2)
for elem in plitted:
    if elem[0] in set2:
        rez=.append('/'.join(elem))
print(rez)
```

Результат

```
['one/two/three', 'seven/eight/nine']
```